# CosmosDB : TransportException - A client transport error occurred

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-durable-functions

Seeing a flood of  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exceptions when client tries to query cosmos.

Upon checking deeper the exception message has details like below:

```
{
   "CPU Load History":{
      "CPU History":"(2021-10-06T19:01:18.6834408Z 82.390), (2021-10-06T19:01:28.5562209Z 89.873), (2021-10-06T19:01:42.1291501Z 93.642), (2021-10-06T19:01:52.6528941Z 90.542), (2021-10-06T19:02:02.7588327Z 90.015), (2021-10-06T19:02:16.2446310Z 91.149)"
   }
}
```

"**IsClientCpuOverloaded**":true

"**TransportException**":"A client transport error occurred: The request timed out while waiting for a server response. (Time: 2021-10-06T19:03:07.1867280Z, error code: ReceiveTimeout [0x0010]

> Exception while executing function: ParseData Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object.{"name":"Typed FeedIterator
> ReadNextAsync","id":"xxx-xx-xx-x-xxxx","caller
> info":{"member":"OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync","file":"ClientContextCore.cs","line":219},"start
> time":"07:02:25:448","duration in
> milliseconds":52503.1979,"data":{"Client Configuration":{"Client
> Created Time
> Utc":"2021-10-06T18:14:08.4529348Z","NumberOfClientsCreated":1,"User
> Agent":"cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.19.0|3.19.1|02|X64|Microsoft Windows
> xx.x.xxxx|.NET Core 3.1.18|N|F 00000001|","ConnectionConfig":{"gw":"(cps:50, urto:10, p:False, httpf:
> False)","rntbd":"(cto: 5, icto: -1, mrpc: 30, mcpe: 65535, erd: False,
> pr: ReuseUnicastPort)","other":"(ed:False,
> be:True)"},"ConsistencyConfig":"(consistency: NotSet,
> prgns:[])"}},"children":[{"name":"MoveNextAsync","id":"xxxx-xx-x-fs-xxxx","caller
> info":{"member":"MoveNextAsync","file":"CrossPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator.cs","line":113}
>
> {"ResponseTimeUTC":"2021-10-06T19:03:07.1875054Z","ResourceType":"Document","OperationType":"Query","LocationEndpoint":"xxxx.azure.com","StoreResult":{"ActivityId":"xxxx-xx-xx-x-xx","StatusCode":"Gone","SubStatusCode":"Unknown","LSN":-1,"PartitionKeyRangeId":null,"GlobalCommittedLSN":-1,"ItemLSN":-1,"UsingLocalLSN":true,"QuorumAckedLSN":-1,"SessionToken":null,"CurrentWriteQuorum":-1,"CurrentReplicaSetSize":-1,"NumberOfReadRegions":-1,"IsClientCpuOverloaded":true,"IsValid":false,"StorePhysicalAddress":xxxxx/","RequestCharge":0,"BELatencyInMs":null,"TransportException":"A
> client transport error occurred: The request timed out while waiting
> for a server response. (Time: 2021-10-06T19:03:07.1867280Z, activity
> ID: xxx-xx-x-xx-xx, error code: ReceiveTimeout [0x0010], base error:
> HRESULT 0x80131500, URI: xxxx/, connection: xx.xx.xx.xx:63676 ->
> xx.xx.xx.xxx:14190, payload sent: True, CPU history: (2021-10-06T18:25:38.6098171Z 100.000), (2021-10-06T18:25:53.9808590Z
> 95.716), (2021-10-06T18:25:58.9272146Z 59.098), (2021-10-06T18:26:15.3087856Z 91.388), (2021-10-06T18:26:18.6269463Z
> 96.000), (2021-10-06T18:26:28.8584330Z 85.611), CPU count: 4)

Comment: FYI please be mindful of tags: `[cosmos]` is unrelated to Cosmos DB (and the tag description calls this out explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

This is an error fixed in 3.20.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard#-3200---2021-06-21

[image: Image of the change log entry with the fix]

Please update to the latest SDK version to avoid it.

Having said that, this is happening during Service Unavailable errors, please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-service-unavailable

From your details, it seems CPU is hot and you might be incurring in thread starvation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-request-timeout#high-cpu-utilization

Your snapshot of CPU is showing both problems:

[image: Issues with CPU diagnostics]